# Calculate product and sum on button press

Tags: javascript, html

I was asked to complete this assignment:

> Create 3 functions and a form. The first function should run when the button is pressed and should use the other 2 functions. The other two functions should calculate the sum of two numbers and the product of two numbers.

See the example below:

> Number1: 2 
>   Number2: 3
>
> Button: Calculate
>
> Sum: 5 
>   Product: 6

I have completed the assignment, but the teacher told me that it's not what he asked for. I keep double checking but I can't see what I am doing wrong. Isn't that exactly what my code is doing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Javascript och funktioner</title>

        <script>
            function getTal1(tal1) {
                var tmpTal1 = tal1;
                return tmpTal1;
            }

            function getTal2(tal2) {
                var tmpTal2 = tal2;
                return tmpTal2;
            }

            function printinfo() {
                var info;
                var tal1 = document.getElementById("tal1").value;
                var tal2 = document.getElementById("tal2").value;

                var summa = +tal1 + +tal2;
                var produkt = tal1 * tal2;

                info = "Summa: " + summa + " Produkt: " + produkt;
                alert(info);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><Min Info</h1>
        <form namn="f1">
            Tal1<input type ="text" id="tal1" name="wed" value="" /><br/>
            Tal2<input type ="text" id="tal2" name="wed" value="" /><br/>
            <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="printinfo()" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: a question titled "javascript code help please" isn't useful for anyone wanting to know what the question is about.

Comment: Uh, your code really doesn't do what was asked in the assignment. "should use" means "should call", and "they should calculate" means "the calculation should happen inside of them".

Comment: I think you just need to read the question

Comment: I'm so new at this. I really can't tell the difference. Can someone help me please? Would be much appreciated! I've tried goggling it, but i can't find anything that helps...

Comment: ask your self these questions, have I made function that sums two numbers?   have I made a function that finds the product of two numbers?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought I had done. And I'm not sure how else to do it...

Comment: you have a function called getTal1,  can you explain how it calculates a sum? or a product?

Comment: What does PEBKAC mean @KeithNicholas

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be creat a form with inputs. Then have a button that calls a function that does your maths with the inputs and calls other functions to do more maths. You have everything there in your code more or less but have not paid attention to the specifics of the questions asked. Hence the ridicule as you post a question asking if you understood the question. The code you need is very easily obtained from w3c schools or any google search. However I would guess that with a small amount of thought from yourself you can easily crack it

Answer (score -3):

The other two functions aren't doing what was asked.  One should be summing two numbers, the other should be multiplying two numbers.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me! I really appreciate it! Any idea how I do that? Do you think you could show me? I'm so new to all of this, but I'm trying to learn.

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer

Comment: If you're trying to learn, then try something yourself. Saying "do it for me" is not the way to learn.

Comment: I am trying myself!! I just started learning javascript last week. And have been working hard ever since to try and complete a couple of assignments. i now have one i can't figure out how to do. So I turned to this site as I heard from friends that they've received a lot of help here. But instead I'm met with ridicule. I'm just trying to get some help. So if you're not will to help. Please don't comment.